# Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/ionic-team/capacitor/ionic-team/capacitor-android/maven-metadata.xml'. Status code 403 from server

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, ionic4

I'm trying to build my ionic 4 application and the build is failing by returning the below error.

> Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/ionic-team/capacitor/ionic-team/capacitor-android/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I have tried offline mode but couldn't be resolved the issue.